# Parallel Port access through python

Tags: python

I am trying to run "parallel" package on my 64 bit system.

```
Import parallel
```

But I am getting this Error. I think this is some DLL problem, but don't know which DLL I need and where to keep them.

```
My_Work\Signal_Generator_GUI\with_parallel.py", line 1, in <module>
    import parallel

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\parallel\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from parallel.parallelwin32 import Parallel  # noqa

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\parallel\parallelwin32.py", line 60, in <module>
    _pyparallel = ctypes.windll.simpleio

  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 435, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: it seems you are trying to import a 32bit package on a 64bits system. Are you sur that you have a 32bit python version?

Comment: how to get 32 bit python version.? i have 64 bit system, while installing python there was no choice for 32-bit or 64-bit python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **simpleio.dll**. Here is a [giveio installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyserial/files/pyparallel/giveio/).
Also, please take a look at this [thread](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/pyparallel-161278.html) for same problem and examples as well. Finally, here is a [github page](https://github.com/pyserial/pyparallel/issues/7) discussing the same issue.